# Unit Test Prism 5 async Delegatecommand executes in parallel

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await, .net-4.5, prism-5

I am writing a unit test for a ViewModel which has a DelegateCommand. This command uses an async method for execution, which is supported since Prism 5 like this:

```
MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () => await MyMethod());
```

Now I have my unit test and I notice, that

```
await model.Command.Execute();
Assert.IsTrue(model.CommandWasRun); // just an example
```

immediately returns (and therefore fails), while the command is run.

The reason I think, that this is a bug, is that in the same unit test everything is fine, if I write

```
await model.MyMethod();
Assert.IsTrue(model.CommandWasRun);
```

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use an `async` delegate in the `DelegateCommand` constructor. You have to use `FromAsyncHandler`:

```
MyCommand = DelegateCommand.FromAsyncHandler(async () => await MyMethod());
```

or, equivalently:

```
MyCommand = DelegateCommand.FromAsyncHandler(() => MyMethod());
```

Comment: Thank you - that's it. I just looked at the source of DelegateCommand and don't understand, why they did not just add another constructor accepting a Func<T,Task> instead of using a Factorymethod that changes the you use DelegateCommand...

Comment: Is there a way to give that method without lambda expression? If not, why is the lambda expression needed. I thought about: 
`MyCommand = DelegateCommand.FromAsyncHandler(MyMethod);`

Comment: @MarkusWeber: You should be able to just pass the method group. I haven't tried it.